# Water + Sugar Solution Preserves Bread?

Tags: bread, sugar, food-preservation, mold

I've heard that by coating bread with a solution of water and sugar can preserve it from mold. Is this true? If not, then my Science Fair Project will be a bust.

Comment: Wouldn't measuring this / comparing coated (different water-sugar ratios!) and uncoated bread be the subject of the exercise?

Comment: Well, I suppose so. My question for the project is basically this: Which sugar preserves bread the longest? Originally, I was going to bake different sugars into the same bread, but I later realized that I didn't have enough time to do that. I had heard that a simpler way to complete that experiment was to coat each bread in a solution of water and sugar. I just wanted to make sure that it would work before I did it, waited the set time limit, and then found out that the solution had not affected the experiment.

Comment: Even if every solution ends up _not_ preserving the bread, that is a reportable result! @Stephie background research is also part of the process, so it isn't totally inappropriate.

Comment: @Erica, that's why I *asked* - unfortunately, we occasionally get some "geniuses" that want us to do their work. I appreciate and support background research very much!

Comment: There's no need to get in an argument. I appreciate both of your help.

Comment: Joy, that is no argument (welcome to the site, btw.!), just friendly clarification. @Erica is also a mod on another site, and sometimes a question is discussed a bit. Your comment / further explanation is quite helpful, btw., perhaps you could [edit](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/65226/edit) your question to include that information?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain the prolonging effect of glazes on baked goods is simply due to the glaze forming a barrier between the pastry and the atmosphere, in effect "sealing" it and preventing the goods from going stale. Thus, the appropriate characteristics would be a glaze that coats the product evenly and thickly enough to prevent moisture loss and oxygenation.